# How to set a VideoView thumbnail?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview, android-glide

I'm working on an Android app where I need to load an image into an ImageView as a placeholder until a video starts playing. I'm using Glide for image loading and a VideoView for playing the video. The video plays fine, but the image does not load as expected.It seems that the video load faster than the image.
I only see a black background and after 1/2 sec the video starts.

```
fun setBackgroundVideo(videoUrl: String, imageUrl: String){
Glide.with(this)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(binding.thumbnailImage)
..
..
}
```

I tried also tried without using an imageView but it didn’t work.
I tried to pause and start the video to the first frame by using seekTo but I still see the black background.
I did some research and I found that:
Glide uses the UI thread
Glide image loading is asynchronous.

The result I want should be this one:
When I go the the page which has the image view i see the first frame of the video and when it’s all loaded it starts.  I don’t want to see the black background but the first frame which is passed as an image url.

Thank you for the help.